# Can't programmatically set permissions to blob container in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

After creating a blob container with `CreateIfNotExists()`, I immediately call `SetPermissions()` to allow users public access to the blobs in the container, but not to the container itself.

Like so:

```cs
CloudBlobContainer pdfContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName.PDFs);

if (pdfContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
    pdfContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
```

The container is created successfully, but when I log in to the Azure portal, the blob container permission is `Private`.

Am I missing an additional call to commit the permission changes? None of the examples that I've looked at seem to show that and I don't see anything in the documentation either. I'm using v2.0 of the Azure SDK.

**UPDATE:**

It looks like `CreateIfNotExists()` is always returning false. I pried the assembly open in Reflector and found that it was catching a (409) Conflict HTTP error and swallowing the exception. This appears to be an issue with either the SDK or the server-side REST implementation. Even though the container does not exist and the container creation succeeds, a 409 is still returned from the server.

It seems like the best thing to do is call `CreateIfNotExists()` and ignore the return value for now.

Also, it is not necessary to call `GetPermissions()` before calling `SetPermissions()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me (I run it on app start-up):

```cs
var blobContainer = GetPhotoBlobContainer();  
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();  
var perm = new BlobContainerPermissions();  
perm.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;  
blobContainer.SetPermissions(perm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either retrieve the container permissions via [`CloudBlobContainer.GetPermissions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblobcontainer.getpermissions.aspx) or create new container permissions, then you can set the [`BlobContainerPermissions.PublicAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.blobcontainerpermissions.publicaccess) property.

```cs
BlobContainerPermissions perms = pdfContainer.GetPermissions(); // get existing permissions
perms.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob; // blob public access
pdfContainer.SetPermissions(perms);

// or create new permissions
BlobContainerPermissions perms =  new BlobContainerPermissions();
perms.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob; // blob public access
pdfContainer.SetPermissions(perms);
```

Comment: SliverNinja, afaik it's not necessary to get the permission and then set it.  You can just create and set it.

Comment: @Fabrizio is correct. You do not need to call `GetPermissions()`.