# Getting images in the Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, xaml, azure, microsoft-metro

there are so many tutorials regarding uploading image files to the azure blob, i have successfully uploaded image file to a blob container and now my problem is how to get it, here is my code:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("http://sweetapp.blob.core.windows.net/userprofiles/"+imagename,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
imgProf.Source = bitmapImage;
```

am I doing it wrong? or is something that i need to do before displaying it? any answers will be appreciated!

**Update:**

this is the code that worked for me

Upload:

```
            var credentials = new StorageCredentials("sweetapp","[my key]");
            var client = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri("http://sweetapp.blob.core.windows.net/"), credentials);   
            var container = client.GetContainerReference("userprofiles");
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(); 
            var perm = new BlobContainerPermissions();
            perm.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(imgName);
            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
            {
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
           }
```

Getting the image:

```
     var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
     bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("http://sweetapp.blob.core.windows.net/userprofiles/"+imagename,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
     imgProf.Source = bitmapImage;
```

Comment: The approach looks right to me. Are you running into any issues?

Comment: yes the image does not show but when i see my blob its there. but then when i try to see it directly eg: http://sweetapp.blob.core.windows.net/userprofiles/killingZ.png some error occurs did i do somthing wrong? and btw i ve updated the question

Comment: You've forgotten line `await container.SetPermissionsAsync(perm);` your code after before `var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(imgName);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the `ACL` on the blob container. I believe the error you're getting is because the container's ACL is set as `Private` (which is the default ACL). For your code above to work, the container's access level should be either `Blob` or `Container`. You may find this link useful for understanding various ACL options on blob containers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179354.aspx.

Try the code below to get/set container's ACL:

```
    storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), false);
    var container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("containername");
    //Get the container permission
    var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
    Console.WriteLine("Container's ACL is: " + permissions.PublicAccess);
    //Set the container permission to Blob
    container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions()
    {
        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob,
    });
```

Comment: ummm the setpermissions part gives me this exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.WrappedStorageException please take note that i am developing in c# xaml thank you!

Comment: btw thanks for your knowledge! your code leads me to here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571433/cant-programmatically-set-permissions-to-blob-container-in-azure-storage

Comment: I tried it with a console application. Let me see how you could do that with a Windows 8 App.

Answer (score 1):

Your codes seems fine. Try to listen to `ImageFailed` and `ImageOpened` event to make sure whether it really fails, or just take some time to load :

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
........
bitmapImage.ImageOpened += (sender, args) =>
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show("Image opened");
                       };
bitmapImage.ImageFailed += (sender, args) =>
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show("Image failed");
                       };
```