# Get Azure BlockBlob Content Type

Tags: c#, azure, blob, containers

I am trying to get "Content Type" from Azure BlockBlob. It's seems like not work.

[image]

This file's "Content Type" is "image/jpeg" as you see.

```
            var cloudConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StoreAccount"].ConnectionString;

            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(cloudConn);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");

            var blocBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("009fc790-2e8e-4b59-bbae-3b5e2e845a3b");
```

And it always returns empty as you see in this picture:

[image]

Comment: See this post (RE: FetchAttributes): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062648/getting-the-file-type-in-azure-storage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var blocBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("009fc790-2e8e-4b59-bbae-3b5e2e845a3b");
```

Code above simply creates an instance of `CloudBlockBlob` and initializes it with default properties. You would need to fetch the blob properties (as mentioned in the answer included in the comment above) and then you will see the properties filled up. To fetch blob properties, you would need to call `FetchAttributes()` method.

```
var blocBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("009fc790-2e8e-4b59-bbae-3b5e2e845a3b");
blocBlob.FetchAttributes();
```

Then you should be able to see the content type property of the blob.

Comment: Great answer. For clarity's sake, after calling FetchAttributes(), you will then have access to the Properties collection and can get the Content Type by simply calling blocBlob.Properties.ContentType.

Answer (score 5):

To get the blob properties you have to first fetch the attributes:

```
blob.FetchAttributes()
```

Then you'll be able to get the content type through:

```
blob.Properties.ContentType
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get it is `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` or `GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync`.  This returns an `ICloudBlob`, which you can do:

```
var blob = container.GetBlobReferenceFromServer("009fc790-2e8e-4b59-bbae-3b5e2e845a3b");
string contentType = blob.Properties.ContentType;
```

Note, this makes a round trip to the server and if the blob does not exist, it will throw an exception.